# How to stretch title view in swift?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I created custom title view for UINavigationItem.
And I want custom view stretch to right padding.
What can I do??

I tried to set rightBarButtonItem to nil.
But it seems no solution.
And don't stretch to left backButton area.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let searchBar = CustomSearchBar()
    searchBar.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
    searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 30)

    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
}
```

See my result. I want a red area.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6owW.jpg

Comment: instead of the default navigation bar, can you use a view to create a navigation bar and place your search bar over it.

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger navigationBar is get-only property.

Comment: I am telling you to don't use the default navigation bar, Add your own view of the same size.

Comment: I think it will be easy for you to just add constraints then.

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger Can you search that way?? I already search that. But only show default navigation bar. Can't find Custom navigation.

Comment: I will update my answer wait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following inside your CustomSearchBar class:

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return UILayoutFittingExpandedSize
}
```

Comment: nice, helped me.

Answer (score 0):

```
let searchBar = CustomSearchBar()

searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar

searchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30.0).isActive = true

searchBar.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.navigationController!.navigationBar.rightAnchor).isActive = true

searchBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.navigationController!.navigationBar.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

The above code worked for me. You can remove the `left anchor` if you do not need the bar in the `center`. I also set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`, I hope this works.